# Paperclip and Heroku without s3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to upload a file using `paperclip` in a production environment in Heroku and the log files show:

```
Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /app/public/system/photos/1/small/081811-2012-honda-cbr1000rr-leaked-003.jpg):
```

Will I *have* to use s3 or similar to handle file uploads, or can I configure path permissions to store the files on Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Heroku does not allows you to add files dynamically to its server.
Though if you need upload feature on a app on heroku you need to configure s3 or other similar services

Refer this for details 
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must use S3 or another persistent store like Rackspace cloudfiles, Dropbox etc.

Whilst you can write to the tmp on all the stacks, the Cedar stack does let you write to the file system but it's not shared across dynos or dyno stop/restarts.

See http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-isolation#ephemeral_filesystem

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is true that Heroku does not allow you to upload files directly onto their servers.  However, you can shove your files into your database. I used a gem created by Pat Shaughnessy:

http://patshaughnessy.net/2009/2/19/database-storage-for-paperclip

It worked well.